# Subjects and Predicative Verbs in a clause

Tags: clauses, subjects

Can you help me in locating the subject and the predicative verb of this dependent clause?

> when you read a lot and expose yourself to different types of writing

Comment: *Read* and *expose* is the predicative verb here.

Answer (score 1):

*You* is the subject; there are two predicates, conjoined with *and*, which are headed by *read* and *expose*.

Comment: If it has a subject and a predicate, then why it is still called a dependent clause? because of "when"?

Comment: @Usernew That's exactly right. It is called "dependent" because it "hangs off" a main clause, and *when* is the hook that it hangs on.

Answer (score 0):

As Usernew says, the subject is "you".  The predicate verb phrase is a conjunction of two verb phrases.  The structure is:

> [S [NP you] [VP [VP read a lot] and [VP expose yourself to different tupes of writing] ] ]

Strictly speaking, there is no "predicative verb".